# NSStream FTP resuming file upload after internet connection lost or application closed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is how i implemented FTP file upload using NSStream ,its working fine with out issues but i couldn't able to figure out how to resume file upload in case if the connection is lost or if the user accidentally closed the app while the upload is in progress.

```
@implementation QFTPOperation

-(id)uploadFile:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSURL *localpath = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    NSLog(@"file url: %@",[localpath path]);

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[localpath path]]) {
        NSLog(@"files exists");
    }

    self.readStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:[[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] path]];
    [self.readStream open];
    NSURL *uploadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://domain.example.com/test.png"];


    uploadUrl = CFBridgingRelease(
                            CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) uploadUrl, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
                            );

    NSLog(@"upload url: %@",uploadUrl);
    self.writeStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                      CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) uploadUrl)
                      );

    [[self writeStream] setDelegate:self];
    [[self writeStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[self writeStream] setProperty:@"foo" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
    [[self writeStream] setProperty:@"bar" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];

    [[self writeStream] open];




    while ([[self writeStream] hasSpaceAvailable])
    {
        NSLog(@"yes ready");
        NSInteger bufferOffset = 0;
        NSInteger bufferLimit = 0;
        UInt8 buffer[1024];

        if (bufferOffset == bufferLimit) {
            NSInteger   bytesRead;

            bytesRead = [self.readStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];

            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                NSLog(@"faild to readstream");
                [self closeStream];
            } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                NSLog(@"read completed");
                [self closeStream];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"bytes read");
                bufferOffset = 0;
                bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
            }
        }



        if (bufferOffset != bufferLimit) {
            NSLog(@"yes waiting to write");
            NSInteger   bytesWritten;
            bytesWritten = [self.writeStream write:&buffer[1024] maxLength:bufferLimit - bufferOffset];
            if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                NSLog(@"failed to write");
                [self closeStream];
            } else {
                bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
            }
        }

    }


    return self;
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"yes stream open");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
                NSLog(@"yes space available");
            NSInteger bufferOffset = 0;
            NSInteger bufferLimit = 0;
            UInt8 buffer[1024];

            if (bufferOffset == bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesRead;

                bytesRead = [self.readStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];

                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    NSLog(@"faild to readstream");
                    [self closeStream];
                } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    NSLog(@"read completed");
                    [self closeStream];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"bytes read");
                    bufferOffset = 0;
                    bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
                }
            }



            if (bufferOffset != bufferLimit) {
                NSLog(@"yes waiting to write");
                NSInteger   bytesWritten;
                bytesWritten = [self.writeStream write:&buffer[1024] maxLength:bufferLimit - bufferOffset];
                if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                   NSLog(@"failed to write");
                    [self closeStream];
                } else {
                    bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
                }
            }

        }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"error occurred");
            [self closeStream];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"error occurred");
            [self closeStream];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)closeStream
{
    [[self writeStream] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[self writeStream] setDelegate:nil];
    [[self writeStream] close];
    self.writeStream = nil;

    [[self readStream] close];
    self.readStream = nil;
}
```

Lets say if the user is uploading 200 MB if he quits the app in the middle say 100 MB uploaded.i want to resume the upload from 100 MB instead of starting over it again.

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: probably you habe to save the number of `bytesRead` and then you can jump in the stream by this offset after reopening it.

Comment: That's seems promising i will try out